# Magento2 plugin does not working on class Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, plugin, di

Create a plugin using for class **`Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping`**. Use after method (`afterCollectRates`) for **`CollectRates`** function.

But this does not work

here  list of files:

- **app/code/AmitBera/CoreRewrite/etc/module.xml**

**code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="AmitBera_CoreRewrite" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Vault"/>
            <module name="Magento_OfflineShipping"/>           
        </sequence>     
    </module>
</config>
```

- **app/code/AmitBera/CoreRewrite/etc/frontend/di.xml**

**code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping">
        <plugin name="disabledfreeShippingforfrontend" type="AmitBera\CoreRewrite\Model\Plugin\DisabledFreeShippingForFront" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

- **app/code/AmitBera/CoreRewrite/Model/Plugin/DisabledFreeShippingForFront.php**

**code:**

```
<?php
namespace AmitBera\CoreRewrite\Model\Plugin;
/**
* Disabled Freeshipping for frontend
*/
class DisabledFreeShippingForFront
{
    public function afterCollectRates(\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping $Freeshipping ,$result)
    {
        $this->_logger->debug(__METHOD__);
         return false;
    }

}
```

Also have the **registration.php**

Also i check the Limitations of plugin  from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

- Does not find any final class at
  Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping
- Does not find any final  Final classes

***Now,Please let me know where i goes to wrong  except this two limited which limitation is create issue in my plugin***

Comment: Magento2 Plugin doesn't work on `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell` too https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/215188/44237

Comment: hi @amit did u get solution for this?

Comment: i have tried Maniprakash Chinnasamy answer but no luck please advise